# FTP disallow listing directory content , but allow uploading

Tags: linux, ftp

I have one FTP account for customers and I want they upload files, but they should not see what already uploaded by other customers.

Is that possible?

If I will disaalow directory listing that will "break" frp connection.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://serverfault.com/questions/24372/is-it-possible-to-setup-a-writeonly-ftp

Answer (score 1):

I've done that with Filezilla server on Windows.  Give the upload directory write but no read permission and they can upload but not download (including not retrieving a directory list).  The only side effect is they get an error in the FTP client when they connect and after they upload.  FTP clients try to pull listings after both events.

Edit:
If you can't have error messages, you'll probably have to grab the files and move them as soon as they're uploaded.  Check out [inotifywait](http://linux.die.net/man/1/inotifywait) from the inotify-tools package or this [article](http://coldattic.info/shvedsky/pro/blogs/a-foo-walks-into-a-bar/posts/31) about using it to move files.

Comment: I had the same results ,but we can not confuse customers with any error messages.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not how the FTP-Protocol works. If you don't want customers to see the files from one another, create multiple users.

Comment: yep, it is not how FTP protocal works, but it may be possible by using  ftp server features (like chaging owner and chmod after uploading)