# OpenSSH in Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: ssh, windows-server-2012-r2, fstab

I'm trying to create a complete FTP server on Win 2012 r2 using IIS FTP (for FTP and FTPS protocol) and OpenSSH for SFTP protocol.

I'm searching for several documentations but I'm discovering different issues; for example, I cannot understand if OpenSSH uses fstab file in its configuration since it is not present in the etc folder installation. also, if OpenSSH uses it, is there a way to configure it or can I simply follow the UNIX rules?

edit:question [Is IIS SFTP natively supported by Windows Server 2012 R2?](https://serverfault.com/questions/648855/is-iis-sftp-natively-supported-by-windows-server-2012-r2) is not the same of mine. in that topic there is a question about the possibility to use SSH on a Win Server 2012 XX. this is not my problem since I know yet that natively it is not supported. 
in fact, I would use another component, OpenSSH for Windows (i.e. http://www.mls-software.com/opensshd.html)but I was trying to understand in a better way its functionalities.

Comment: Since when does OpenSSH run on Windows?

Comment: @Hyppy http://sourceforge.net/projects/sshwindows/ , https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FZyUX-LZHts

Comment: @JimB Ahh, Cygwin.  Makes sense.

Comment: I removed my comment, make more sense

Comment: Is it worthwhile reopening this as OpenSSH has a native port to Windows? https://github.com/PowerShell/openssh-portable

Answer (score 2):

Save yourself some headache and find an SSH server that was designed to run on Windows instead of an SSH server that was designed to run on *nix and hacked to run on Windows via a compatibility layer like Cygwin.

There are some excellent choices highlighted in this previous answer:
[What is a good SSH server to use on Windows?](https://serverfault.com/questions/8411/what-is-a-good-ssh-server-to-use-on-windows)